# VariableDeclaratorld expected after this token

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax-error

I am having a lot of trouble solving this error.  Please help. The error is with fxRates.

```
    private HashMap.String.Long.fxRates = newHashMap<String.Long>(40);
```

Comment: Where did you learn Java syntax? Why don't you learn it?

Comment: Periods, periods everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `,`  not `.`

```
private HashMap<String,Long> fxRates = new HashMap<String,Long>(40);
```

Please read some [`basic java tutorial`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/) before proceeding.